# Training on sequences of sentences using Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am working on a project where I have to use a combination of numeric and text data in a neural network to make predictions of a system's availability for the next hour. Instead of trying to use separate neural networks and doing something weird/unclear (to me) at the end to produce the desired output, I decided to use Keras' merge layer with two networks (one for numeric data, one for text). The idea is that I feed the model a sequence of performance metrics for the previous 6 hours in the shape of (batch_size, 6hrs, num_features). Alongside the input I am giving to the network that handles numeric data, I am giving the second network another sequence of the size (batch_size, max_alerts_per_sequence, max_sentence length).

Any sequence of numeric data within a time range can have a variable number of events (text data) associated with it. For the sake of simplicity, I only allow a maximum of 50 events to accompany a sequence of performance data. Each event is hash encoded by word and padded. I have tried using a flatten layer to reduce the input shape from (50, 30) to (1500) so that the model can train on *every* event in these "sequences" (to clarify: I pass the model 50 sentences with 30 encoded elements each for every sequence of performance data).

My question is: Due to the fact that I need the NN to look at all events for a given sequence of performance metrics, how can I make the NN for text based data train on sequences of sentences?

My Model:

```
#LSTM Module for performance metrics
input = Input(shape=(shape[1], shape[2]))
lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_layer_count, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=shape))(input)
dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.2)(lstm1)
lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_layer_count, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False))(dropout1)
dropout2 = Dropout(rate=0.2)(lstm2)

#LSTM Module for text based data
tInput = Input(shape=(50, 30))
flatten = Flatten()(tInput)
embed = Embedding(input_dim=vocabsize + 1, output_dim= 50 * 30, input_length=30*50)(flatten)
magic = Bidirectional(LSTM(100))(embed)
tOut = Dense(1, activation='relu')(magic)

#Merge the layers
concat = Concatenate()([dropout2, tOut])
output = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(concat)

nn = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input, tInput], outputs = output)

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.8, nesterov=True, decay=0.001)
nn.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy', coeff_determination])
```

Comment: I don´t understand your question in detail., maybe you can rephrase it? I am working with something similar. I also have text data and numerical data. In my case I have n sentences, where every sentence (seq of words in embedding space) is going through its "own" LSTM but the weights are shared. Finally I put all LSTM output into a 1D convolution and after that concat with the numerical data.

Comment: It seems like you understood the question just fine, but I'll try to rephrase it anyway! Given both numeric and text data containing multiple sentences per instance of numeric data points (encoded into word vectors of length 30), how do I train a model that leverages both types of data?
To your suggestion: 
I'll give that approach a try. However, if you're training N LSTMs for N sentences, isn't that horribly slow in both training and predicting even though you are still sharing the weights?

Comment: Yes that would be horrible slow, in the case you have one LSTM for each sentence, in my case we are not exactly talking about sentences, its more like messages. But from with some adjustment it could work. Does [this](http://digital-thinking.de/deep-learning-combining-numerical-and-text-features-in-deep-neural-networks/) describe your problem?

Comment: Yes, that link definitely captures what I am trying to do. However, it appears that this implementation only handles sequences of numeric data and individual messages rather than sequences of messages. 

In other words, instead of going from:

"The cat purred" -> [1, 2, 3] -> Model.

I need to go from:

"The cat purred" -> [1,2,3]            
"The dog barked" -> [1, 4, 5]        
"The dolphin swam" -> [1, 6, 7] -> [1,2,3; 1,4,5; 1,6,7] -> Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as far as I understood you have a sequence of max 50 events, which you want to make predictions for. These events have text data attached, which can be treated as another sequence of word embeddings. [Here](http://digital-thinking.de/deepchat-recurrent-neural-networks-for-dialog-classification/) is an article about a similar architecture.

I would propose a solution which involves LSTMs for the text part an 1D-convolution for the "real" sequence part. Every LSTM layer is concatenated with the numerical data. This involves 50 LSTM layers, which can be time consuming to train, even if you use shared weights. It would be also possible to use only convolution layers for the text part, which is faster, but does not model long term dependencies. (I have the experience, that these long term dependencies are often not that important in text mining).

Text -> LSTM or 1DConv -> concat with numerical data -> 1DConv -> Output
Here is some exmaple code, which shows how to do use shard weights

```
numeric_input = Input(shape=(x_numeric_train.values.shape[1],), name='numeric_input')
nlp_seq = Input(shape=(number_of_messages ,seq_length,), name='nlp_input'+str(i))

# shared layers
emb = TimeDistributed(Embedding(input_dim=num_features, output_dim=embedding_size,
                input_length=seq_length, mask_zero=True,
                input_shape=(seq_length, )))(nlp_seq)    
x = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))))(emb)      

c1 = Conv1D(filter_size, kernel1, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(kernel_reg))(x)
p1 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c1)
c2 = Conv1D(filter_size, kernel2, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(kernel_reg))(x)
p2 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c2)
c3 = Conv1D(filter_size, kernel3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(kernel_reg))(x)
p3 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(c3)

x = concatenate([p1, p2, p3, numeric_input])    
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)        
model = Model(inputs=[nlp_seq, meta_input] , outputs=[x])
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And training:

```
model.fit([x_train, x_numeric_train], y_train)
# where x_train is a a array of num_samples * num_messages * seq_length
```

A complex model like this needs a lot of data to converge. For less data a simpler solution could be implemented by aggregating the events to have only one sequence. For example the text data of all events can be treated as one single text (with a separator token), instead of multiple texts, while the numerical data can be summed up, averaged or even combined into a fixed length list. But this depends on your data.

As I am working on something similar, I will update these answer with code later on.

Comment: Thank you @Digital-Thinking for your help. Would TimeDistributed do essentially the same thing? From what I understood of the documentation, the TimeDistributed layer applies the target layer to every slice of the input. To me this means that the model will automatically create a LSTM layer for every alert in the sequence which accomplishes the same thing as the for loop in the above code.

Comment: Very good hint! I think TimeDistributed also works, but you input data have to be in the proper format. I will update the answer tomorrow